# Service 'hdfs' check failed: java.net.UnknownHostException - Hortonworks

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

hi I m learing in Hortonworks, I m facing a problem when ever I

> open ambari -> Files View, or Hive, Pig.

how can i solve this,

Issues detected
Service 'hdfs' check failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: sandbox.hortonworks.com

Collapse Stack Trace
[image]
Service 'hdfs' check failed:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: sandbox.hortonworks.com
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.initialize(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:179)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi$1.run(HdfsApi.java:70)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi$1.run(HdfsApi.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.execute(HdfsApi.java:397)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.<init>(HdfsApi.java:68)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsUtil.connectToHDFSApi(HdfsUtil.java:127)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.commons.hdfs.HdfsService.hdfsSmokeTest(HdfsService.java:136)
    at org.apache.ambari.view.filebrowser.HelpService.hdfsStatus(HelpService.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariAuthorizationFilter.java:257)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.AmbariAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AmbariAuthenticationFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.MethodOverrideFilter.doFilter(MethodOverrideFilter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.AmbariPersistFilter.doFilter(AmbariPersistFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.doFilter(AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.view.ViewThrottleFilter.doFilter(ViewThrottleFilter.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:212)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:201)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.handle(AmbariHandlerList.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sandbox.hortonworks.com
    ... 121 more
```

I m newbie. please kindly guide me. i m using Hortonworks of docker in windows .

Update:

As per PRE-REQUISITES I have added like this in

```
c/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts
```

> ## localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
>
> 127.0.0.1       sandbox.hortonworks.com
>
> 192.168.XX.XX       sandbox.hortonworks.com
> [image: hosts file]

Still i have getting the error . Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding what you're doing - you're running Hortonworks hadoop in a docker container, and trying to connect to it from some software in the host machine?

Comment: yes actually running hortonworks hadoop in docker container. I m just trying to create tables and to work with Hive using this `http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-process-data-with-apache-hive/ `

Comment: One of the first prerequisites for using the sandbox is to put `sandbox.hortonworks.com` into your `/etc/hosts` file. Have you done this?

Comment: oh thanks, I m learning. i didnt done this, actually can u elaborate what should i do now. which file (eg: HDP_2.5_docker.tar) and where should i place it. i m using windows machine .

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming from inside of the sandbox virtual machine from hadoop itself. Updating your Windows c/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts will only help you to resolve that hostname to access that web ui from a browser using the hostname. The Hadoop Sandbox is a virtual machine, you have to update it inside of the Virtual Machines operating system, which is most likely Linux.

You will need to open a terminal session into the Virtual Machine using a client such as PuTTy which you can find free out there for download. Open Putty the input the ip address of the sandbox to open an ssh connection to it. In the hostname field of putty enter 127.0.0.1 then for the port enter 2222 then press okay. You will maybe be prompted to accept a host key, press okay. You should be prompted for a username, enter root as the user name. It shouldn't ask for a password. Then you should have a terminal prompt in linux, run the following to echo the hostname to /etc/hosts file.

cat /etc/hosts;

echo "127.0.0.1 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox localhost" >> /etc/hosts

To check updates;

cat /etc/hosts;
ping sandbox.hortonworks.com

Exit your terminal session then try configuration again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C11Wi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the prerequisites](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/) for running hortonworks hadoop in docker. What you're probably missing is an entry in your hosts file. Here's the excerpt from the link:

> If on windows 7, to add sandbox.hortonworks.com to your list of hosts, open git bash, enter the following command, replace {Host-Name} with the appropriate host for your sandbox:

```
echo '{Host-Name} sandbox.hortonworks.com' | tee -a /c/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts
```

Comment: thanks , let me check and let you know. here Host name is my PC hostname-  localhost or (eg: CP00234) or ipaddress ?

Comment: Either should work.
Also, make sure that the docker image is exposing the needed ports.

Comment: yes, thnx, I have followed ur prerequsities but also issue not solved. I have added 127.0.0.1 sandbox.hortonworks.com in hosts file. :(

Comment: The second entry, `192.168.XX.XX` should be removed.

Comment: Ok thanks, i didnt get solution but for ur efforts I provide bounty.